# Getting undefined is not a function error when using Pickadate with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, datepicker

I am using pickadate (date and time picker) in my Meteor app.  I had it working fine before, but suddenly it is no longer working.  It may be related to the fact that I am now calling the template dynamically using `Template.dynamic`.

Here is my code:

```
Template.hlesson.rendered = function() {
    $('#lesson_date').pickadate({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
    var $start_input = $('#lesson_start_time').pickatime({
        interval: 15
    });
    var $end_input = $('#lesson_end_time').pickatime({
        interval: 15
    });
}
```

I am able to use the select2 plugin on the same page successfully, but get the following error in the console:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: undefined is not a
>   function TypeError: undefined is not a function

The error seems to be coming from the pickadate function, but I am confused as to why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are those elements (lesson start and end time) rendered conditionally (inside of an `each`, `if`, etc.)?

Comment: @DavidWeldon No, they are just rendered normally in the template.  The template is loaded dynamically, which may be a factor.  The strange part is that I also use select2 on the page with `$('#studentList').select2()` and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This meens some of the element do not exist when you run this snippet of code. Try add this to your code:

```
console.log($('#lesson_date'));
console.log($('#lesson_start_time'));
console.log($('#lesson_end_time'));
```

And see if the elements exist. Maybe you are running this code on wrong page or before DOM content is ready (for that see [$(document).ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))

Comment: When I run this all three jQuery elements do exist and print in the log.

Comment: Check the .length property of the elements. If jQuery cant find element, it creates it and shows this freshly created element. But since it is not inserted into DOM tree, it has .length = 0

Comment: The .length property outputs 1 for each